# How does Openstack cinder on controller node make NFS share of volumes available to compute node?

Tags: openstack, nfs, cinder

NFS mount on compute node under the covers using brick?

Leveraging NFS support in libvirt?

Just don't understand the magic.

Answer (score -1):

https://github.com/openstack/cinder/blob/master/cinder/volume/drivers/nfs.py The code does all the magic :)

Comment: Is the share mounted on the compute node or does the compute node access the volume through the share on controller node?

Comment: Its your choice how you design/architect your infra.